# how can I make electron open an exe file with a button

Tags: javascript, html, electron, exe

so I am trying to make my own games launcher for fun but I was wondering how could I make a button open one of them using electron. eg. minecraft button opens minecraft.exe

Comment: Yeah kinda but how can i make it open the file with a button because now it's opening automatically when i start the program

Comment: I made it work with onclick() but it only opens images or other files but it doesn't open exe files what can i do?

Comment: Can you share your code snippet?

Comment: Maybe the exe file path is wrong or permission issue. But mostly exe path is wrong.

Comment: okay so it works but for it to work i need to create a shortcut of the exe file that i want to use and then add it to my folder and run it like that. it wont let me run it externally